Continuous selection from an upper hemicontinuity correspondence
Given a u.h.c. correspondence $\phi: X\rightrightarrows Y$ (see here for a definition of u.h.c correspondence), a function $f:X\to Y$ is called a continuous selection from $\phi$ if $f$ is itself a continuous function and $f(x)\in \phi(x)$. For simplicity, we could just think $X$,$Y$ are subsets in Euclidean spaces.
It is known that a continuous selection needs not to exist for a u.h.c correspondence. For example, one can consider the following u.h.c correspondence.
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(x)=
\begin{cases}
0, \mbox{ if } x< 0\\
[0,1],\mbox{ if } x=0\\
1,\mbox{ if } x>1
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
I am wondering if some extra condition could guarantee a continuous selection, at least locally. For example, if $\phi(x)$ is singleton-valued at $x_0$, could we always find a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$ satisfying that $f(x)\in \phi(x)$ on this interval? This conclusion seems to be intuitively true if we assume in addition that $\phi$ is compactly-valued and use that u.h.c implies $Graph(\phi)$ is closed.
If we don't know that $\phi(x_0)$ is singleton-valued, but know that there is an isolated point $y_0$ in $\phi(x_0)$, could we always find a continuous selection that passing through $(x_0,y_0)$? Is there a selection theorem guarantees this kind of results?

You would need lower hemicontinuity, see, e.g., selection theorems, to get the existence of a continuous selection.
If your upper hemicontinuous map $\phi$ is a singleton at $x_0$, then every selection $f(x) \in \phi(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$.
The following function is u.h.c with $(x_0,y_0) = (0,1)$ is an isolated point of the graph but there is no continuous selection of $\phi$ passing through $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$
graph (\phi) = (\mathbb R \times \{0\}) \cup  \{ (0,1)\}.
$$

Is your example u.h.c at 0? Isn't this a classic example showing that closed graph isn't sufficient for u.h.c if the range is not contained in a compact set?

This new example is nice. Thanks for that. I knew that Michael selection theorem holds for lower hemicontinuity case. Unfortunately, I could only have upper hemicontinuity for $\phi$ as a result of the continuous Maximum theorem.
